# SQL Server failover for mirror database in SQL Sever 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, database-mirroring

I am using sql server 2014 with mirroring. My .net application goes into non responding mode when trying to connect to database when I use the connection string below.

```
Server=Server1IP; Failover Partner=Server2IP; database=dbname; uid=sewebsite;pwd=somerndpwd;Connection Timeout=0;Pooling=True
```

But it works in below cases:

- If I remove mirroring and I use above connection string.
- If I remove
  "Connection Timeout" parameter from connection string and use
  mirroring.

Please suggest the possible reasons behind this issue.

Comment: `Server=Server1IP; Failover Partner=Server1IP` is this misprint or you really intend to mirror server by itself?

Comment: Sorry, that is a typo error while putting the question here. It is : Server=Server1IP; Failover Partner=Server2IP; database=dbname; uid=sewebsite;pwd=somerndpwd;Connection Timeout=0;Pooling=True